# List append not working with Tkinter Combobox

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter, combobox, append

Since I am very new to Python, I'm having an issue while trying to append element selected thanks to combobox inside an array. I would like to append selected element in order to filter data inside my data frame.
I hope it's clear, hard to explain it textually.
Thank you for your help.

```
data = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\gdeange1\\dev\\Reco_engine\\IMPORT_RECO_SYSTEM.xlsx')

df = data.parse('DATA_PYTHON',index_col=False,na_values=['NA'])

df['SwTelNo'] = df['SwTelNo'].astype(str)


df = df.reset_index()

from tkinter import *

import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk

from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import column

from tkinter import  Label, Button, FALSE, Tk, Entry, StringVar

from tkinter.ttk import *

app = tk.Tk()

app.title("Reco Engine Tool")

app.geometry('500x400')


def callbackFunc(event):
   global Province
   print("Province selected : " + event.widget.get())

def callbackFunc1(event):
   global Heading
   print("Heading selected : " + event.widget.get())

def callbackFunc2(event):
   global Tier
   print("Tier selected : " + event.widget.get())

def callbackFunc3(event):
   global Channel
   print("Channel selected :" + event.widget.get())

def click():
   print(Province.get())
   print(Heading.get())
   print(Tier.get())
   print(Channel.get())

listPROVINCE = []

number1= StringVar(app)

keepvalue1 = number1.get()

Province = tk.Label(app,text = "Choose your Province")

Province.grid(column=0, row=0)

Province = ttk.Combobox(app, values=
["QUEBEC","ALBERTA","ONTARIO","ALIANT", "BRITISH COLUMBIA", "SASKATCHEWAN", "MANITOBA"], textvariable=keepvalue1, state='readonly')

Province.grid(column=0, row=1)

Province.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event:callbackFunc(event))

listPROVINCE.append(Province.get())

listHeadingCluster = []

number2= StringVar(app)

keepvalue2 = number1.get()

Heading = tk.Label(app,text = "Choose your Heading Cluster")

Heading.grid(column=0, row=2)

Heading = ttk.Combobox(app, values=["A","B","C","D","E","F"], 
textvariable=keepvalue2, state='readonly')

Heading.grid(column=0, row=3)

Heading.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event:callbackFunc1(event))

listHeadingCluster.append(Heading.get())

listTier =[]

number= StringVar(app)

keepvalue = number.get()

Tier = tk.Label(app,text = "Choose your Tier")
Tier.grid(column=0, row=4)

Tier = ttk.Combobox(app, values=["1","2","3","4"], 
textvariable=keepvalue, state='readonly')

Tier.grid(column=0, row=5)

Tier.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event:callbackFunc2(event))

listTier.append(Tier.get())

listChannel =[]

number3= StringVar(app)

keepvalue3 = number3.get()

Channel = tk.Label(app,text = "Choose your Province")

Channel.grid(column=0, row=6)

Channel = ttk.Combobox(app,  values=["Premise","Advantage","Acquisition", "RPT20", "RPT19", "Client 
Relations", "Retention", "Assignment Center", "Cmr", "Canyps Pub", 
"Diamond", " Diamond Biz Dev", "Direct Mail"," DoNotAssign", "Dormant Accounts", "House Accounts", "Manitoba Special Accts", "Non Sales", "Retention Premise", "Special Channels", " Third Party Acquisition", "Unassign"], textvariable=keepvalue3, state='readonly')

Channel.grid(column=0, row=7)

Channel.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event:callbackFunc3(event))

listChannel.append(Channel.get())

tk.Button(app, text="Click Here", command=click).grid(column=0, row=9)

app.mainloop()

dataset_2 = df[(df.Tier.isin(listTier) & (df.PROVINCE.isin(listPROVINCE)) & (df.HeadingCluster.isin(listHeadingCluster)) & (df.Channel.isin(listChannel)))]

dataset2 = dataset_2.reset_index()`
```

I would like to stock the element selected using combobox inside an array.

For example, for Provinces, I'll select "ALBERTA" and append this into `listPROVINCE`.

Same for the other 3 arrays (`listHeadingcluster`),(`listTier`),(`listChannel`).

I tried to use `.current()` and it worked. For example, in Provinces, I set `Province.current(1)` to get "ALBERTA", `Heading.current(0)` for "A", `Tier.current(0)` for "1" and `Channel.current(0)` to get "Premise".

Here is the error I got when I tried `Province.get()`, `Heading.get()`, `Tier.get()`, `Channel.get()` :

> ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required by check_pairwise_arrays.

Comment: Your `ValueError` **is not** a `tkinter` Error. Remove **all** `tkinter` from your Questions code and leave only the `pandas` ones. Setup your Variable `Province` etc. as described in your Question. Run the **7** `pandas` code lines. Retag with `[pandas]`

Comment: You are importing tkinter three different ways, and ttk two different ways - you have five import statements where you only need two. That's not a part of the problem, but it definitely will make your code harder to understand.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley I have changed these duplicated imports.